# Calculate value on part of a Many-to-Many relationship in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have a Many-to-Many relationship: dishes to their ingredients through link table.

[image]

I want to display a pivot table showing all ingredients of each dish with cost of each ingredient part and total cost of each dish. You should get the idea from the picture below except that actual values are somewhat spoiled. And here is why. `cost of ingredient` is a measure calculated by the following expression: `=CALCULATE(SUM(dishes_ingredients[quantity])*SUM(ingredients[price]); dishes_ingredients)`

Should I use calculated columns instead in `dishes_ingredients` and how do I properly reference `ingredients` table from there? Or should I take totally different approach?

[image]

I'm quite a newbie to Excel and that's sort of hobby, would be glad also if you recommend succinct, but comprehensive (overviewing concepts and gently moving to practical parts) reading.

Comment: You should use calculated columns. To get price of ingredients from ingredient table, use `VLOOKUP()` formula. And for reading, I recommend this book: https://archive.org/details/Wiley.Excel.2013.Power.Programming.with.VBA.Mar.2013

Comment: @bzimor I'm more interested in Excel (particularly in PowerPivot) as a user, not as a VBA developer, do you think it would still be helpful?

Comment: In this book you can get more poverful tools, tips about excel formulas as well as pivot tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, should have tried before posting. Calculated column is what I had to do. Was afraid to mess with column indices in VLOOKUP, but those are nicely referenced by their names in DAX.

`=[quantity]*LOOKUPVALUE(ingredients[price]; ingredients[ingredient_id]; [ingredient_id])`

[image]

And everything is now how it was mean to be.

[image]

Still open for suggestions on a good DAX/PowerPivot book.